# Dynamic select boxes in Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am learning Angular and have dynamic select boxes in jQuery that ask for the number of children. The select boxes dynamically change according to how many are selected to then ask for the children's ages.

This is working correctly however seeing they are dynamic they are losing state within my Angular app if the page is reset.

I am using a session cookie for the other data.

What is the best way to wrap this into Angular?

```
$(document).on("change", "#children", function() {
    var $div = $('.add-wrap'); //Select the appending div
    var $select = $('<div class="pull-left col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1"><fieldset class="form-group">'
        +'<label class="ach-search" for="children">Age</label>'
        +'<select class="form-control" name="age" id="age">'
        +'<option value="0">0</option>'
        +'<option value="1">1</option>'
        +'<option value="2">2</option>'
        +'<option value="3">3</option>'
        +'</select>'
        +'</fieldset></div>').appendTo('.add-wrap')
    $select.clone();
    var index = this.selectedIndex; //get the number of select
    $div.empty(); //Erase old select
    if(!index) return; //Stop the code if the number of child is 0
    for(var u=0; u<index; u++){//Get the number of child
        var $clone = $select.clone(); //Clone the template
        $clone.appendTo($div);
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: One thing's sure: Dont use jQuery to build dom elements anymore. That's the philosophy with angular. Use ng-repeat

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let's give you a hint.

Here is how you would do it with angular (not tested, but just so you get the idea):

```
Number of children 
<input type="number" ng-model="childrenCount" ng-change="updateChildren()" />
<select ng-repeat="c in children" ng-model="c.age">
   <option ng-repeat="a in possibleAges" ng-value="a">{{a}} years</option>
</select>
```

And in your controller :

```
$scope.updateChildren = function(){
    var c = $scope.childrenCount;
    if(!$scope.children)
        $scope.children = [];
    else if($scope.children.length>c)
        $scope.children.splice(c,$scope.children.length-c); // remove last elements
    while($scope.children.length<c)
        $scope.children.push({age:1}); // add children
};
$scope.possibleAges= [1,2,3,4];
```

Using this, $scope.children contains an array of object, each one having a 'age' property bound to one of the generated select boxes.

No more jQuery as you can see.

Comment: Thanks heaps for this. I just need to edit the push on the number of children. Eg ...If it is  3 - shows an array ages:[4,3,6] instead of {age:4},{age:3},{age:6}

Answer (score 0):

Angular has a built-in directive for dynamically generating a list of options in a select element. It is called [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).